# didDeselectItemAtIndexPath in collection view is not firing when you deselecting a cell

Tags: ios

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UIImageView *img;
        UICollectionViewCell *myCell=[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        img=(UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:101];
        if (myCell.selected) {
            [myCell.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images-2.png"]];
        }

        [collectionView reloadData];
    }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UIImageView *img;
        UICollectionViewCell *myCell=[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        img=(UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:101];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];
       [collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with `[collectionView reloadData];`
after reload data you will change image in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
  -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath)
    {
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected image"]];
    }
    else
    {
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     selectedIndexPath=indexPath.row;
     [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Note: initially set selectedIndexPath= -1,it indicate no selection in collection view

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!how to get selectedcell?

Comment: Thanks NANNAV its was a great help!i want your id to contact..Please

Comment: @mubibegum there is no personal chat available in this site, add your questions in this site, any one help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `reloadData` from within the delegate callbacks. This can easily lead to undefined behavior and also cause the problem you mentioned about the collection view not handling selection states correctly.

Usually calling `reloadData` removes all selections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!am not reloading the cell but i want change the image for the cell..Can you suggest how to do that?